# Рабочий парсер 2Gis

Tags: php, парсер

Подскажите, где можно найти рабочий парсер 2Gis? Нужно собрать список организаций с полями: наименование, телефон, адрес, рубрика. Желательно на PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть рабочий [Парсер 2Gis](https://parselab.org/parser-2gis.html).
Он не на PHP, но там есть API для управления базами через CLI, так что можно работать с ним на любом языке программирования.